# Getting the value of json

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

Aloha, i am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRMY8fIj8cs) and here is a [Git of it](https://github.com/PrettyPrinted/AJAX_Forms_jQuery_Flask)

I was pretty successfull with it but now i am trying to modify this code a little bit :)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

Persons = [{'name' : 'Arnold' , 'email' : 'disceps@gmail.com'},
           {'name' : 'Alex Mikro' , 'email' : 'kovalsky@gmail.com'}, 
           {'name' : 'Phost Arnold' , 'email' : 'arn@gmx.de'}]
```

So, i've created the following value

For now, i would like to get a POST responce from this...So, if a name is equall to the typed name, there should be a responce..

```
@app.route('/pers', methods=['POST'])
def addOne():
    email = request.form['email']
    name = request.form['name']

if name and email:
    pers = [persons for persons in Persons if persons['name'] == name]
    pers[0]['name'] = request.get_json(force=True).get('name')    
    if name == pers[0]:
        return jsonify({'name' : name})


return jsonify({'error' : 'Missing data!'})
```

but unfortunately,this doesn't work..

p.s. the code mentioned in the video

```
def addOne():
email = request.form['email']
name = request.form['name']

if name and email:
    newName = name[::-1]
    return jsonify({'name' : newName})

return jsonify({'error' : 'Missing data!'})
```

is working without any troubles :)
So i think, there is a problem in my IF-Statement...

Answer (score 1):

OK. A lot going on in there. Per Davidism, please explain what you are attempting to do.

Issues:

- You have a list with multiple dictionaries in your original example.
- Then you have a form where you are taking in values from two fields(`'email'` and `'name'`) and assigning them to variable (`email` and `name`)
- Then, if the variables are populated, you are constructing a list (`pers`) with a list comprehension, where `pers` will contain any dictionary from the `Persons` list with a `'name'` value that matches the `name` variable. Why?
- Then I lose you. The code after that seems to do multiple unnecessary tasks.

Almost everything under `if name and email:` makes no sense as a whole. If you explain what your intent is, I think someone can help. As it is, I can't see what you planned to do.

The example you provide from the video is not doing what you are doing. It is making a new variable `newName` from the variable `name` which is derived from the form (`name = request.form['name']`). Why it is making `newName` a reversed version of `name` I don't know, but even with that it is doing something far simpler than you appear to be attempting.